# How can I obtain a screenshot of a post that doesn't show my personal voting choice?

Tags: support, voting, privacy

If I want to share a screenshot of a non-deleted post on Stack Overflow but, for some reason, don't want to disclose in the screenshot my personal voting choice (while still keeping the score information), I can use a private browsing window to display the post without being logged in.

However, I cannot do this for a deleted post (or a post on a private Team) because they cannot be viewed by an anonymous user.

How can I *generically* make a screenshot of *any* post without disclosing my personal voting choice *and* without changing the displayed score (which would be the result if I retracted my vote, took the screenshot, and then restored my vote—if that would even be possible, due to vote locking).

Comment: A change so small doesn't even deserve a user-script. Just "inspect" the voting button and remove the `vote-down-on` class.

Comment: But then people will think you _didn't_ vote, and this could be resented as well.

Comment: @Jean Do not tell anyone of this... but in theory you _could_ subvert these sophisticated hacking techniques to doctor the screenshot and make it look as if you had actually **up**voted the question!

Comment: @yivi you mean MSPaint => fill the triangle with the proper color? :p

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre no, just the vote-up-on class.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre The best way is to highlight *both* the upvote and the downvote button! Everyone will understand that that is not correct.

Comment: @user202729 [I don't know what you're talking about](https://i.imgur.com/6jg6WCG.jpg) :)

Answer (score 52, accepted):

Open up your browser's JavaScript console and execute this:

```
$('.js-vote-down-btn, .js-vote-up-btn').removeClass('fc-theme-primary');
```

This should remove all the "voted on" styles from the page, so you can take a screenshot without revealing your voting preferences.

If you want to remove your favourite preference as well,

```
$('.js-favorite-btn').removeClass('fc-yellow-600');
```

These work on both public Q&A as well as private teams as they use the same CSS classes.

Comment: If you want to redact the page instead, I have a userscript which removes the above and masks the users' display names [RedactedScreenshots](https://github.com/samliew/SO-mod-userscripts/blob/master/RedactedScreenshots.user.js)

Comment: @SamuelLiew I just want to make a point to commend your efforts to making the mod tools a better place for everyone. Looking at the work you've put in, I can see that you were a good choice for the mod team.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit some historical info: *[Why are lookbehind assertions not supported in Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30118815)*. Anyway I've gone ahead and removed it from the userscript.

Comment: @SamuelLiew Aha, ES2018! That explains it. Thanks

Comment: This seems like a rare instance that this question could have been on topic for both meta & main.

Answer (score 0):

Quickest way on Windows:

1. <kbd>Prt
   Scrn</kbd>
2. <kbd>⊞ Win</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>
3. <kbd>pbrush</kbd>, <kbd>Enter</kbd>
4. Crop
5. Scribble over the voting widget with a nice fat red paintbrush
6. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd>
7. <kbd>screenshot.png</kbd>, <kbd>Enter</kbd>

Comment: Honestly this is the way I'd go if possible, although I'd probably draw a filled rectangle instead, because it makes the redaction of my voting choice open and above board, not via stealth.

Comment: @DanNeely A big messy blob of red digital paint is not stealth, but the filled rectangle is probably easier now you mention it (if anything I'd find a neat shape to be closer to "stealth" tbh)

Comment: To be clearer, I meant that editing an image was the non-stealth way to do it.  Fiddling with the web page using debug tools as in @yivi 's answer would be doing it via stealth.

Comment: @DanNeely Ah :)

Comment: How is this "Quickest"?

Comment: @Eric By virtue of the fact that it takes the least time to do. Unless you're really slow with MS Paint.